# How to use PrintDialog to print a multi-line textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextBox (m_txtFieldToSearch), and what's in the control's contents should be printed. My method currently prints a blank page.

```
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

        printDoc.DocumentName = GlobalConstants.AppName;

        printDialog.Document = printDoc;
        printDialog.AllowSelection = true;

        printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;

        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            printDoc.Print();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to print your textbox control's contents?

Comment: RTFM: See [PrintDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: GrawCube, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if this helps.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

            //PrintPage event to draw the textbox contents on page
            printDoc.PrintPage +=new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage);

            printDoc.DocumentName = "Print";

            printDialog.Document = printDoc;
            printDialog.AllowSelection = true;

            printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;

            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                printDoc.Print();
        }
        private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //Font
            Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial",10,FontStyle.Bold);

            //Brush
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            //Where to draw the string
            PointF p = new PointF(10,10);

            //Draw some strings into the graphics
            e.Graphics.DrawString(m_txtFieldToSearch.Text,f,b,p);
        }
```